ReactNative : App Crash on startup after upgrading Expo to 52
in short :
I've upgraded Expo to 52 and ReactNative to 0.76. Every thing is fine on iOS but the Android App crash after the splash screen with the following LogCat error:
com.facebook.soloader.SoLoaderDSONotFoundError
Details:
I had no information in console, no error screen shown from expo. Trying to launch the app from Android studio allows me to see LogCat output with this error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 6990
com.facebook.soloader.SoLoaderDSONotFoundError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreact_devsupportjni.so
  existing SO sources: 
      SoSource 0: ApplicationSoSource[DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~qKc0DTlTD-nAinarNfLR-A==/com.myapp.app-GmHt0JpTfAXh90BbDjNSoQ==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]]
      SoSource 1: DirectApkSoSource[root = [/data/app/~~qKc0DTlTD-nAinarNfLR-A==/com.myapp.app-GmHt0JpTfAXh90BbDjNSoQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a]]
      SoSource 2: DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 3]
      SoSource 3: DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 3]
  Native lib dir: /data/app/~~qKc0DTlTD-nAinarNfLR-A==/com.myapp.app-GmHt0JpTfAXh90BbDjNSoQ==/lib/arm64
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:1216)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:1078)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:943)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryOnAndroid(SoLoader.java:859)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:842)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:812)
  at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportSoLoader.staticInit(DevSupportSoLoader.kt:21)
  at com.facebook.react.devsupport.InspectorFlags.<clinit>(InspectorFlags.kt:16)
  at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.createBundleURL(DevServerHelper.java:408)
  at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.createBundleURL(DevServerHelper.java:378)
  at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.getJSBundleURLForRemoteDebugging(DevServerHelper.java:477)
  at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase.getJSBundleURLForRemoteDebugging(DevSupportManagerBase.java:638)
  at expo.modules.devlauncher.rncompatibility.DevLauncherBridgeDevSupportManager.<init>(DevLauncherBridgeDevSupportManager.kt:50)
  at expo.modules.devlauncher.rncompatibility.DevLauncherDevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevLauncherDevSupportManagerFactory.kt:33)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:275)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:364)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:87)
  at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:29)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:57)
  at expo.interfaces.devmenu.ReactHostWrapper.getDevSupportManager(ReactHostWrapper.kt:63)
  at expo.modules.devmenu.react.DevMenuPackagerCommandHandlersSwapper.swapPackagerCommandHandlers(DevMenuPackagerCommandHandlersSwapper.kt:22)
  at expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuManager.setUpReactInstance(DevMenuManager.kt:111)
  at expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuManager.setDelegate(DevMenuManager.kt:405)
  at expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuManager.initializeWithReactHost(DevMenuManager.kt:410)
  at expo.modules.devmenu.DevMenuPackage$createReactActivityLifecycleListeners$1.onCreate(DevMenuPackage.kt:38)
  at expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt:181)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:47)
  at com.myapp.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:9002)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8980)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1526)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4030)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4235)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:112)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeNonLifecycleItem(TransactionExecutor.java:174)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeTransactionItems(TransactionExecutor.java:109)
        2024-11-21 10:00:25.755  6990-6990  AndroidRuntime          com.myapp.app                     E      
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:81)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2636)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8705)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)

I've found this is probably due to React native library version alignment, I've tried to update libs and select it carefully.   (see dependencies from package.json below)
I've created a brand new project with Expo 52 tools,  it creates a project using new expo-router system. I don't use it. Expo 52 release notes say we can keep using React navigation v6 That's why I stayed on 6.* version for react Nav.
In the new projet there is an entry "main" in package.json set to : "expo-router/entry". I've never had it, should it be set ? (I use ./App.jx as my entry point)
It seems I'm missing some migration steps. Currently checking the new Splashscreen feature, I'll update the question if I find more information.
Thank you for any help.
Dependencies :
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~4.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.5.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^11.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "1.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "expo": "~52.0.7",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~7.1.2",
    "expo-blur": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.13.1",
    "expo-checkbox": "~4.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~5.0.3",
    "expo-device": "~7.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-haptics": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.2",
    "expo-location": "~18.0.2",
    "expo-modules-core": "~2.0.4",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.29.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-symbols": "~0.2.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
    "i18next": "^22.4.15",
    "intl-pluralrules": "^2.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.44.3",
    "react-i18next": "^12.2.2",
    "react-native": "0.76.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
    "react-native-iap": "^12.13.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.18.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^18.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.5.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "react-native-webview": "13.12.4"
  },


I've finally succeed in this update in 3 steps :
First I've replaced the "expo/splash" in app.json to the config plugin "expo-splash-screen" :
(the image has to be a logo and not a full size splash screen img)
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-splash-screen",
    {
      "backgroundColor": "#def9f9",
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png"
    }
  ],

then I've regenerate the full android folder running :
npx expo prebuild --platform android --clean

Be careful, as this will erase any changes made to the build.gradle file, if there are any, you'll need to apply them again.
I think this is the important step as it updates a SoLoader.init config in MainApplication.kt:
    SoLoader.init(this, OpenSourceMergedSoMapping)

Finally a minor error occcurs in AndroidManifest.xml about an Attribute being present twice :
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color@resource value=(@color/notification_icon_color) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:88-137
    is also present at [:react-native-firebase_messaging] AndroidManifest.xml:40:13-44 value=(@color/white).

=> add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to allow it to override previous setting.
These steps solves my issue,
Hope that helps.
